# How to do arithmetic query in SOLR search

Tags: solr, lucene

Now, Let's say I want to search all SOLR documents with length below 3000 (End - Start).
Is that feasible somehow with SOLR query syntax? if not are you familiar with some open source that is able to do that?

I know this is not SOLR "role" (only indexing..) but still I'm looking to see if that's possible?

```
{
    "id": "XXX",          
    "Timing": [
      "Start: 1000 | End: 2000",
      "Start: 3000 | End: 5000",
}
{
    "id": "YYY",          
    "Timing": [
      "Start: 9000 | End: 10200",
      "Start: 13000 | End: 14000",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you define length ? Chars or words ? You could do both of them but i think words is a bit trickier. To do chars, just use an https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor and fill in a predefined length field for the document. You could do the same for words, but you'd have to analyze the document, get the word count , then fill it in, which could prove to be expensive time-wise , especially if you have a lot of update traffic .

EDIT : To use the range query in solr just have a look at lucene's query syntax :http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_2/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package_description, then pass the query string into a qParser, or just straight into the solr server : length:[* TO 3000] will get you all docs with length lower than 3000 for example

Comment: thanks. In this example I define length as (End - Start) of the field (numeric values).

Comment: Maybe I confused you with "length" term. Let's say I want to subtract two fields as a condition for query - in my example [field End - field Start].

Comment: i guess you could have a look at function queries then. You can pretty much do anything with those : http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery

Comment: mmm didn't find that logic there...more of sorting results etc.